How to configure Visual Studio Code for which JVM to use on OSX
I am trying to get VS code to use another version of java after upgrading my gradle.
No matter what I do VS code keeps referring to the wrong JVM when invoking gradle.
In setting.json, I added:
"java.import.gradle.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/",
"kotlin.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/",
"java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/",
"java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/",

(i know that last one is deprecated, but I am not seeing the forest through the trees in terms of configuration options. And I find resources on Internet are more in the 'try this' area, than the  'here's how to do it'.
I also added:
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-21",
            "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",
            "default": true
        }
    ]

I have exported JAVA_HOME:
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

and when I start a zsh shell: echo $JAVA_home reports
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

which is the same as where the JavaSE-21 above is pointing to.
I also added, in build.gradle:
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

after adding
plugins {
    id "java-library"
}

java --version in the terminal reports:
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.2, mixed mode, sharing)

Yet, when I build a gradle project, it still complains about java versions, pointing to a JRE installed by Android Studio, inside it's application package.
There are no references to java in any of the gradle files inside my project. (which there shouldn't be as otherwise the project would prescribe it, while it is an environment setting that can change across devellopers.

If you don't apply gradle, will a normal java project correctly apply the jdk settings in settings.json? If so, then please modify the relevant gradle configuration to get the correct jdk version.
